# Single series of data on an excel chart (line) is reversing its order

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am creating a simple line chart in excel, using 4 data series against date (in the form of YYYY).

Three of these series are financial, and displayed against the primary axis.

One is non-financial, and displayed against the secondary axis.

The non-financial series is displaying with it's order reversed (i.e. the value for 1993 is occuring in 2020, the value for 2020 is occuring in 1993, etc.)

I have tried creating the graph both by selecting all data at once, and by individually adding each data series to the graph separately - but still the same problem.

Any help gratefully received, I am sure I am missing something painfully obvious!

---

EDIT #1 - to include data, unsure of how to upload file, so example given:

| Year | Number of Units | Unit 1 | Unit 2 | Unit 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 3 | £10 | £15 | £7 |
| 2019 | 3 | £8 | £13 | £7 |
| 2018 | 2 | £7 |  | £6 |
| 2017 | 1 | £7 |  |  |
| 2016 | 1 | £4 |  |  |
| 2015 | 1 | £3 |  |  |

On producing graph, the individual unit prices are displaying correctly correlated to the relevant date. The Number of units series however is displaying on the line chart as follows:

2020 - 1
2019 - 1
2018 - 1
2017 - 2
2016 - 3
2015 - 3

Comment: Not able to reproduce the problem. Please post data and issue you observe.

Comment: @Isolated - Thank you, please see above edit - hope this clarifies.

Comment: My guess is this. Right-Click on your secondary axis (whatever axis has your nbr_of_units) and select format axis. Under Axis Option , make sure the checkbox for "values in reverse order" is NOT selected. Other than that possible issue, I've got nothing.

Comment: @Isolated Thanks very much - has worked. I had assumed that changing the order of values was universal, not axis-by-axis!

Answer (score 2):

Answered in comments above, many thanks to @Isolated.

> Right-Click on your secondary axis (whatever axis has your nbr_of_units) and select format axis. Under Axis Option , make sure the checkbox for "values in reverse order" is NOT selected.

Unfortunately, as his answer was merely a comment I'm not able to properly thank him by formally accepting his advice.

Comment: While isolated's comment was useful, it would be good to flesh that out into a fuller answer based on what worked for you. If someone else has the same issue, they can refer to your answer and benefit from both your experiences.

Comment: @Glorfindel - sorry, as I stated - Isolated's answer was given as a comment, not an answer, so I could not accept it. I did, however, want to highlight his assistance. If there is a way to do so, happy to alter what I have done.

Comment: @TKCZBW sorry, that isn't obvious from the review queues. Right now it's a lot better, thanks!